# Sticky header issue on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, sticky, onscroll

I want to do sticky header on scroll for this I have written following code

```
var body = document.body;
var scrollUp = "scroll-up";
var scrollDown = "scroll-down";
var lastScroll = 0;

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("scroll", scrollHandler);
}

function scrollHandler() {
  var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
  if (currentScroll === 0) {
    body.classList.remove(scrollDown);
    body.classList.remove(scrollUp);
    return;
  }
  if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains(scrollDown)) {
    // down
    body.classList.remove(scrollUp);
    body.classList.add(scrollDown);
  } else if (currentScroll < lastScroll && body.classList.contains(scrollDown)) {
    // up
    body.classList.remove(scrollDown);
    body.classList.add(scrollUp);
  }
  lastScroll = currentScroll;
}
```

Sticky header is working but its flickerring for some resolutions also It got stuck also sometime. Please help me in this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using sticky position attribute in CSS.

```css
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: gray;
}

main {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h3>StickyHeader</h3>
</header>
<main>
  contents
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to select the nav element instead of body 
check the snippet the navbar will be fixed when you scroll up only

```js
  var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
        var scrollUp = "scroll-up";
        var scrollDown = "scroll-down";
        var lastScroll = 0;

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
        } else {
            window.attachEvent("scroll", scrollHandler);
        }

        function scrollHandler() {
            var currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
            if (currentScroll === 0) {
                nav.classList.remove(scrollDown);
                nav.classList.remove(scrollUp);
                return;
            }
            if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !nav.classList.contains(scrollDown)) {
                // down
                nav.classList.remove(scrollUp);
                nav.classList.add(scrollDown);
            } else if (currentScroll < lastScroll && nav.classList.contains(scrollDown)) {
                // up
                nav.classList.remove(scrollDown);
                nav.classList.add(scrollUp);
            }
            lastScroll = currentScroll;
        }
```

```css
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2000px;
        }

        nav {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background: royalblue;
        }

        .scroll-down {
            position: static;
            top: initial;
            left: initial;
        }

        .scroll-up {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <nav></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

position sticky is not widely supported.
you can try this approach without Javascript
https://jsfiddle.net/59gd7a6e/1/

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }

            header {
                background: #efefef;
                height: 50px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            section {
                height: 500px;
            }

            section:nth-of-type(2n) {
                background: #ffeda9;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        This is the header
    </header>
    <section>
        section 1
    </section>
    <section>
        section 2
    </section>
    <section>
        section 3
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```